Running POST via Playwright in C#
I've tried to send a Post command to a Rest API using playwright,
it does not wait until the page redirects to the json respond and returns the js challenge page (one like cloudflare) as the result, which can't convert to json and throws an exception.
private IPlaywright _playwright;
private IBrowser _browser;
private IBrowserContext _context;

public async Task InitializePlaywrightAsync()
{
    _playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
    _browser = await _playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions { Headless = true });
    _context = await _browser.NewContextAsync();
}

private async Task<JObject?> PostToUrlAsJObject(string url, StringContent content)
{
    try
    {
        string con = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var response = await _context.APIRequest.PostAsync(url, new()
        {
             DataString = con,
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Content-Type", "application/json" },
                { "Accept", "application/json" },
                { "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" },
                { "Referer", url },
                { "Origin", new Uri(url).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) },
                { "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9" },
                { "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br" }
            },
        });

        string res = await response.TextAsync();
        return JObject.Parse(res);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error during POST request:\r\nURL: {url}\r\nError: {ex.Message}\r\nStack Trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
        return null;
    }
}

Haven't seen a similar question for C#...

What are you automating and what are you trying to do on it? Please share a [mcve]

@ggorlen there's not much to it, for example the url parameter is the api's login url and the content is username and password as a json string

All right, but what's that API endpoint URL and which page are you running this on? I need to be able to run this or at least compare the request payload to what the endpoint expects in order to fix your problem. The code here is a perfectly standard looking POST as far as I can tell, so there's no obvious eyeball solution. The problem exists in the interactions between the page and the API in addition to the code. Even if it was obvious from the code, it's still best/standard to have a reprex.

@ggorlen see when you open a site and it first goes to cloudflare's challenge page? it returns that page instead of the result, it doesn't wait for the necessary redirect. and it's not the same as cloudflare's page, it has no captcha to solve it's just a js challenge

Ah, this is the first time you've mentioned cloudflare. You might want to [edit] that into the question, along with complete context for which page you're automating and what you want to achieve on it. If you don't want to share the site, pick another one with close-enough behavior. There may be another way to bypass detection than this--Playwright runs JS normally for challenges as far as I know, so I don't see any obvious failure point off the top of my head.

If you're automating a page and trying to hit its API, and you can't do this by clicking a button on the page, why not make a fetch request with included credentials from the browser context?

You don't need to launch browser to do API testing in Playwright using c#
as explained in the official link you can use this to get a request context
  private IAPIRequestContext Request = null!;

and then call the API
    Request = await this.Playwright.APIRequest.NewContextAsync(new() {
        // All requests we send go to this API endpoint.
        BaseURL = "https://api.github.com",
    });
    var newIssue = await Request.PostAsync("/repos/" + USER + "/" + REPO + "/issues", new() { DataObject = data });

Remove that browser code if you just want to test Post API
